# PHP copydir function problems

Tags: php

I am having some problems with the below function which is suppose to copy a whole directory and its contents - the opendir line returns Unable to Open every time and I don't know why. The source does exist and it has 755 permissions (also tried it with 757 permissions and still no luck!).

Can anyone suggest anything?

```
function copydir($source,$destination)
{
    if(!is_dir($destination))
    {
        $oldumask = umask(0); 
        mkdir($destination, 0757); // so you get the sticky bit set 
        umask($oldumask);
    }

    $dir_handle = @opendir($source) or die("Unable to open");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
    {
        if($file!="." && $file!=".." && !is_dir("$source/$file")) //if it is file
        {
            copy("$source/$file","$destination/$file");
        }

        if($file!="." && $file!=".." && is_dir("$source/$file")) //if it is folder
        {
            copydir("$source/$file","$destination/$file");
        }
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);
}
```

Comment: Why do this in php? The os is made for this: `exec(cp source dest);`

Comment: it is a php based site on a server I dont have access too except via ftp so really need a php solution

Comment: Remove the `@` so you see actual error messages

Comment: @Mogria: are there other systems around then? just kidding, on Win one could use copy. Still not wise to do this in php

Comment: hmm strange remove the @ makes no difference and no errors are displaying??

Comment: Solved it! very odd but I guess there must have been a corrupt file in my source files as deleting them from the server and uploading them again fixed it

Answer (score 0):

On what platform are you running this? I just tried it out on windows and it works perfectly well.